# prolog constraints

Tags: prolog, constraint-programming

I have the function

```
test(X, Y, Z) :-
   { Z = Y+X },!.
```

When i run the queries

```
test(1,X,8), test(X,4,8), test(1,5,X)
```

I am able to get a value for X, but if i do

```
test(X, Y, Z) :-
   { Z = Y**X },!.
```

I get errors for each query similar to

Unhandled exception: Unknown message: type_error(nf(_G353**1,_G351),1,a numeric expression,_G353**1)

I tried other operators and they all work, I'm guessing that ** is special, but how exactly do we handle it?

Comment: see the first half of http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/0809/Prolog/Prolog08ML2R2.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean ** to indicate exponentiation, the operator you want is ^; ** isn't a valid operator in prolog, hence the error message.

Comment: Wow, that simple, thanks a million. I looked up using power and found that it was **. It worked, but not when I did constraints. You're ^ has everything working fine now. I guess ** is outdated or something. Thanks again.

Comment: ** is the exponentiation operator for prolog, but you were working within the constraint library, where ^ is used instead.  That also explains why you didn't need to use is, as @andrew_cooke alluded to in his comments, to do arithmetic evaluation.